# Vim command to open zathura immediately after a latex compile?

Tags: vimrc, command-line, compile-vim, nvim

I have the following line in my nvim configuration file:

```
map <leader>c :w! \| !compiler <c-r>%<CR>\| !zathura $(echo %:r".pdf") && disown<CR><CR>
```

The first part (or 2/3 of the line) works to compile the file I'm working, but I want to bring up zathura when this happens. Can I modify the last bit? It's my best guess but it doesn't work right now.
Also, I don't want multiple instances of zathura to be open (If I say, compile and then recompile).

I should add that the compiler command automatically runs pdflatex.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the [vimtex plugin](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex).

It allows opening zathura as a PDF viewer after compiling in one step. Also it has continuous mode, meaning that you will be able to see automatically compiled changes immediately in the running zathura instance.

Answer (score 0):

If the currently active file is your main file (which the `!compiler` invocation already assumes), you can open the corresponding pdf with

```
!zathura '%<'.pdf&;disown<cr>:redraw!<cr>
```

The `:redraw!` part is not strictly necessary.

This doesn't solve the "don't open another instance" part of your question. This could be done with a boolean indicating that `zathura` was already called...

Comment: This doesn't work for me, when I try to use the command on it's own, the bottom of the vim terminal flashes for a second and nothing changes.

Comment: I have the vim file open as blah.tex , this may be why. How do I change this in vim cmd line?

Comment: :! zathura $(echo "%" | cut -f 1 -d '.').pdf opens the file , but I wan't to open in a new dwm window. How do I do this?

Comment: Im thinking something like zathur --fork foo.pdf, but this doesn't work on the command line

Comment: @mtheorylord the `&` does fork it into the background. And I use the above command for productive use since years ago (without the `;disown` part)... And it should open `blah.pdf` if your currently active buffer's name is `blah.tex`.

Comment: @mtheorylord remove the `:redraw!<cr>` to see what the command actually returns (instead of the flashing).